# Alternative proof that ring of functions does not contain any nontrivial multiple of the exponential function

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, ring-theory, alternative-proof

Let $R$ be the ring generated by $\{\sin, \cos, \sec\}$, closed under scalar multiplication by $\mathbb{R}$, and accompanied by a derivative operator $D$.

The following hold:

- $D(\sin) = \cos$
- $D(\cos) = -\sin$
- $D(\sec) = \sin \sec^2$
- $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$
- $\cos \sec = 1$

Consider the equation $Dx = x$; it's a differential equation.

Let $S$ be the ring consisting of analytic real functions defined almost everywhere. I add in the defined almost everywhere constraint to cover the fact that $\sec$ is technically not a total function of the reals.

Within $S$, the solution to $Dx=x$ is $\{ r\exp : r \in \mathbb{R} \}$.

$0$ is in $R$ and is a solution to $Dx=x$.

I claim that it is the only solution in $R$.

We can prove this by noting that any unbounded function in $R$ approaches positive or negative infinity as its argument approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Whenever $r \neq 0$, $r \exp$ is unbounded. However, it doesn't approach positive or negative infinity as its argument approaches $\frac{\pi}{2}$, therefore it is outside of $R$.

Alternatively, we could prove this by noting that every function in $R$ is periodic, and the only periodic multiple of $\exp$ is $0$, since $\exp$ is not periodic as a real function.

However, solving this problem in this way required pulling in a lot of information about how real functions behave, rather than treating the functions abstractly.

**Is there a way to prove this algebraically, by appealing to the ring structure of $R$, the linearity of $D$, and the facts that we know about $D$?**

Comment: The periodicity argument does require essentially nothing. I doubt that there is an easier way to prove this algebraically. Which facts about $D$ would you like to use?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven So I started with the intended interpretation of this ring, where one function is $\sin$, one is $\cos$, and one is $\sec$, but I could have started with $f,g,h$ and modded out by some relations defining $Df, Dg, Dh$. I'd like a strategy that works in cases where I don't have particular concrete functions in mind and just specify some relations constraining the derivative.

Comment: I'd like to use "as few facts about $D$ as possible", but I don't have a precise list of facts that about $D$ that don't nail down $R$ but do allow the proof to go through that would make this question better-posed. This isn't an exercise from a textbook, so there's no guarantee that there's a satisfying answer here.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood your motivation. I thought you'd like to have an easier proof, but you are striving for a method which applies in a more general setting. Unfortunately, I do not know the answer to your question, but I do like it.

Comment: Derivation lifts to complex numbers and $D(\cos + i\sin) = i(\cos + i\sin).$ Derivation can be extended to any rational function of $\cos, \sin$ uniquely. If $t =\cos + i\sin$ then every element of extended ring has unique representation $R_1(t) + R_2(t)\cos$ where $R_1(t), R_2(t)$ are rational functions.

Comment: Do you want $R$ to be closed under application of $\mathrm D$?

Comment: I think you have to assume something more about $\mathrm D$, this isn't enough. I don't see how you get derivatives of products from this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way of solving $f'=f$ with integrating factors from analysis still works algebraically. Put slightly differently, whenever $Dx=x$, $$D(\frac{x}{\exp})=\frac{D(x)\cdot\exp - xD(\exp)}{\exp^2}=0$$
So $\frac{x}{\exp}$ is a constant. Here we only used three facts:

- $D\exp = \exp$
- The quotient rule $D\frac{f}{g}=\frac{Df\cdot g - f\cdot Dg}{g^2}$, which can be deduced from the Leibniz rule $D(f\cdot g)=Df\cdot g + f\cdot Dg$.
- $Df=0$ iff $f$ is a constant.

While it's not needed in this problem, often it's easier and more elegant to consider the [differential field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra) $\mathbb C(z, e^z, e^{iz})$, which can be regarded as a subfield of the meromorphic functions over $\mathbb C$ (and in your case, we may consider only $\Bbb C(e^{iz}, e^z)$ without $z$.). Note that $\sin, \cos, \sec$ can all be defined with $e^{iz}$ alone. Most ways to solve ODEs can be symbolically carried out in $\mathbb C(z,e^z, e^{iz})$.

**Edit.**  Upon reading the formulation of the question again, it seems the OP is assuming $X:=\{r\exp \mid r\in\mathbb R\}$ are all the solutions in $S$, and the problem is whether $X\cap R=\{0\}$, which is not addressed above. Well, here is a straightforward approach to show there is no nonzero solution in $\mathbb C(x)$ where $x=e^{iz}$ and since $R\subset \mathbb C(x)$, we're done.

Indeed, given $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\in \mathbb C(x)\setminus\{0\}$, we have (based on $Dx=ix$ and chain rule) $$ \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=D[\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}] = \frac{p'q-pq'}{q^2}Dx = \frac{p'q-pq'}{q^2} ix$$ $$pq = (p'q-pq')ix$$

If the leading term of $p$ and $q$ are $a_mx^m\not=0$ and $b_nx^n\not=0$ respectively , comparing the leading terms of the two sides above, we get $$a_ma_nx^{m+n}=(m-n)a_ma_nix^{m+n}$$ $$(m-n)i=1$$ which is impossible since $m-n\in\mathbb Z$.

In this approach, we have used the quotient rule and the chain rule $Dr(x)=r'(x)Dx$, which makes sense in a field when $r$ is a ratio of two polynomials and could be established from the Leibniz rule.

Further we can actually show that $x=e^{iz}$ and $y=e^z$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb C$. Indeed if $$\sum_{m,n}a_{mn}x^ny^m=0$$ is a minimal algebraic relation between $x,y$, then by taking derivative on both sides, we get $$\sum_{m,n}a_{mn}(in+m)x^ny^m=0$$

Now we can cancell the leading term in $\sum_{m,n}a_{mn}x^ny^m$, contradicting the minimality, unless all $(m+ni)$ are equal, so there is a single term, but this is impossible as $x^my^n\not=0$.

Comment: (+1) I have two questions: 1) shouldn't we rather consider the field $\Bbb C(e^{iz})$ instead of $\Bbb C(e^z)$? (I think this was essentially the idea of @dsh's comment). 2) In the *ring* $\Bbb C[e^z]$, is there an "easy" (pedestrian) way to prove that if $D(u)v-uD(v)=0$ and $v\ne0$ then $u=0$?

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the comment. 1) Yeah, you're right, I was careless. Updated. 2) Formally this implies $D(u)/u = D(v)/v$, $\ln(u)=\ln (v)$, so $u/v=\lambda$. So you mean $u=\lambda v$? I guess the point is not allowed to use division? But in this specific case, we do know $D$ extends to $\mathbb C(e^z)$, so the method of considering $D(u/v)$ is still valid (as often we use rational numbers to prove a theorem about integers).

Answer (score 5):

An element of $R$ writes uniquely
$$x=\sum_{i\in\Bbb Z}a_i\cos^i+\sum_{i\in\Bbb Z}b_i\cos^i\sin$$
where only finitely many $a_i$s and $b_i$s are nonzero real numbers.
The equation $Dx=x$ is then equivalent to
$$(\forall i\in\Bbb Z)\quad a_i=(i+1)b_{i+1}+(2-i)b_{i-1}\quad\text{and}\quad b_i=-(i+1)a_{i+1}.$$
Using the second equation to substitute the $b_i$s in the first one, we derive
$$(\forall i\in\Bbb Z)\quad (i^2-2i-1)a_i=(i+1)(i+2)a_{i+2}.$$
This implies
:

- (by induction) $(\forall i<0)\quad a_i=0$,
- $a_0,a_2,a_4,\dots$ are either all zero or all nonzero, hence actually all zero,
- similarly $a_1,a_3,a_5,\dots$ are also all zero,
  i.e.
  $$(\forall i\in\Bbb Z)\quad a_i=0$$
  and therefore
  $$(\forall i\in\Bbb Z)\quad b_i=-(i+1)a_{i+1}=0,$$
  which proves that the only solution $x\in R$ of $Dx=x$ is $x=0$.

Comment: I was thinking this, but then I am wondering what happens when we don't have a basis. For example, if we instead let $R$ be the rational functions in $\sin$ and $\cos$, i.e., $R = \text{Frac}(\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 -1))$. The same periodic argument should work to show that no solution in $R$ exists, but it seems harder to show using just the algebraic properties since there isn't a clear $\mathbb{R}$ basis.

Comment: @JakeZweifler An answer to [my comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4833712/timeline#comment_10291526) would solve your problem, I think.